# Creating an Ubuntu live USB for use with Gparted

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, resize

I've install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Windows 7 Dell laptop. Recently I discovered that I'm running out of space on my Ubuntu partition, and I would like to enlarge it.

Is it safe to resize partitions while they're in use e.g. when I'm logged into Ubuntu? If so, I've ran into this problem when I run **GParted**: It seems as if my hard drive is one big, NTFS partition, like the Ubuntu partition doesn't exist.

Is it possible Ubuntu runs off the NTFS partition, sharing it with Windows? What should I do?

Comment: Seems like you installed via wubi. Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation

Comment: you can remove ubuntu and reinstall it with Appropriate installation size

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a liveusb/livecd to partition your harddrive. Acer recently sent my sister's computer with a 70 gig partition for her personal files to go into??? We had to boot into Ubuntu to add it to her windows partition becuase we only had 2 megs free. I don't think it would be very safe to partition the drive while you're using it though and be sure to backup all your personal data using Ubuntu and Microsoft's only data clouds (or another harddrive) as there's always that chance.

Also, did you install it using Wubi?