# Problems to boot, Ubuntu entry does not work anymore

Tags: 12.04

A few months I decided to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC alongside with my Windows 7 partition. In order to do that and avoid any mistake, I followed these steps:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/2/

Everything was going well until I decided to update to the 12.10 realese. I don't know what happened, but after I updated my Ubuntu, it stoped working, it didn't even launched, when I turned on my pc and choose to run "Ubuntu 12.04" on the Grub Screen, a weird messaged appeared.

Well, so I decided to install the Ubuntu 12.10 and forget about the 12.04 partition, no problem. I erased the partitions used for the Ubuntu 12.04 with EaseUS partition Manager.

However, when I start my PC, there is still the option of "Ubuntu 12.04" to chose, is that bad?

And what about now, can I use the Windows Installer of Ubuntu ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows ) to install the Ubuntu 12.10 ? What should I do to have Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7 in dual boot again?

Thanks; Thales.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly, a sureshot solution:**

1. Uninstall wubi installations.
2. Free up space by deleting partitions.
3. Install by booting from a live disk.

Why not wubi ?? (good read)
[What's the difference between Wubi and a regular "alongside Windows" installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

**To answer your first question:**

The fact that you still get grub after deleting the ubuntu partition means that your original installation(12.04) was done using Wubi as well. Then just deleting the partition will not tell wubi that the installation has been removed. That is the reason the entry is still showing up. ( your first link isnt really accessible, thats why im guessing that you used Wubi for 12.04 insallation ). If you feel having a dead link to an old installation is bad, then yeah, its bad. Apart from that, it wouldn't really do you any harm.

*ps:Im still curious about the "wierd message". Not that it will change the solution, but will help me know what really went wrong with the upgrade.*