# Do I need to format windows drive only or the whole hard disk?

Tags: installation

I want to install ubuntu on my dell notebook, currently it is running windows 7. My question is: Do I need to format windows partition (i.e. C:/) only or the whole hard disk to make an installation of ubuntu?
second question is: If I need to format windows partition only, would I be able to access data in my other partitions on the same hard disk having ntfs file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ist question

No you dont need to delete ANY partition. You can make Dual Boot system along with Windows either by using wubi that comes with Ubuntu or completely independent OS. In case of WUBI it will be installed on same Partition e.g C:\ as an app but will give you option during boot to which OS you want to use and good thing about it that you can it uninstall it just like any other app from Uninstall section of Windows. OR

if you want to have a only ubuntu as the OS, then choose `Somthing else` option in ubuntu installer.

Identify the c: drive. `Delete` it.

Create a new partition using file system as `ext4` and mount point as `\`.

Then continue to installation.

For 2nd Part

Yes u can access other partitions like NTFS thats the beauty of Linux.

Hopes this answers. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to format any of the partition, you can simply use wubi installer, it will install as easily as any software or on a specific partion for which you will need to format one partition and rest of the partitions will be accessible from both windows and ubuntu

see [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular "alongside Windows" installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

Comment: I no longer want to keep windows, want to use ubuntu as sole OS on my notebook.

Comment: then format only windows partition and the one other partition of around 200MB which was automatically created if you are using windows7.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT have to format the partition on which you installed windows, that's completely unnecessary. 
Just add another Partition, by removing space from different partitions.
When you have a live-CD or DVD of Ubuntu you can change your partitions while installing ubuntu with gparted.

Comment: would I be able to access my data on other partitions then which have an ntfs file system?