# How do I delete Ubuntu installed with Windows system dual-boot?

Tags: installation, windows, uninstall, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows XP on a different partition and I want to delete Ubuntu while retaining the Windows XP. I don't want that my Windows gets damaged in the process. How can I do this?

[image: Screenshot of partitions in Windows tool]

Comment: It looks like you have installed Ubuntu on the 4.28 GB partition (no letter assigned, according to your image). Can you confirm it? In that case, you'll have to ask in a Windows forum how to delete a logical partition.

Comment: Whatever you do, please please please back up all your important data first, both in Windows and Ubuntu ...

Comment: yes  Ubuntu on the 4.28 GB partition  and 1.25 GB it is Was created after the installation of Ubuntu Now How do I delete Ubuntu?

Comment: I do not format the disk C It contains windows, and I can not install it again with Ubuntu it requires a lot of time Is there any solution?

Comment: If i do delete logical drive Ubuntu from Windows the usual way will go Ubuntu and windows will remain??Or there is a special way to delete these tablets?

Comment: You have to ask in a Windows forum 1) how to delete a logical partition and 2) how to resize a partition

Comment: where is the window forum ?

Comment: @Ed Villeges: uninstalling Ubuntu, even from Windows, is on-topic. See this question on meta: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5596/what-windows-questions-are-ok-to-ask

Comment: I edited your question to indicate that Ubuntu and Windows are on different partitions, as is obvious from the screenshot. In the future, I recommend using Wubi if you're just trying Ubuntu, it makes uninstalling Ubuntu very easy. See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation

Comment: @Flimm You are right, this question is an absolute dupe of that one.

Comment: @Flimm This question is different from the one you provide, because this user is able –as far as I can see– to run Windows as well as Ubuntu. However, some answers there solve it, namely, the OS-Uninstaller option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the picture it seems you have Windows on the C: (NTFS) partition, as it is labeled "System". Then Windows and Ubuntu are on separate partitions. To delete Ubuntu you just have to format both partitions labeled as "Unknown", and no harm to both your C: and D: partitions will be done.

Comment: ok i will do and tell you what i do

Comment: Is there a special way to format logical drives or conventional way?

Comment: The only logical partition seems to be C:, while the others are inside an extended partition (green marker). You do not want to format the logical one, as it holds your Windows installation. In the "Disk Management" section from where you took the screenshot, just right-click on it and choose "Format" each of the partitions. If you want you can even "Delete" each of them and then expand D: to the rest of the HDD.

Comment: Delete both of them then. If you want to create new partitions you can then format the remaining space, or you can just expand D:

Comment: @Ahmedsaber: if this answer satisfies you, please accept it by clicking the tick symbol next to the post. You'll get two reputation points for doing so.

Comment: @JoãoAndré And what happens with the GRUB after delete the Ubuntu partition?

Comment: @Lucio: If he was using GRUB as the bootloader (which he never mentioned), then he would be would have to restore MBR to be able to boot into XP again. However, that was not the topic's question. Anyway, there are plenty of ways to do that from within an Windows XP installation [like this](http://schivmeister.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/uninstall-linux-fix-mbr-from-within-windows-xp/).