# Does the windows installer replace windows or format the disk?

Tags: installation, windows, wubi

When installing Ubuntu 12.10 with the Windows installer (from Windows 7). Does the installer just replace the Windows "software" but keep all my files, or does it completely format the disk and delete all my files?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

It just installs Ubuntu as a stand-alone application (or just like any other application) running in Windows. No seperate partitions are created and Windows stays intact as it was.
You can always uninstall Ubuntu like any other application within Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the windows installer from windows 7, it partitions your drive, giving you two separate operating systems on one HDD.

You get prompted with options to what you want to do with your installation.

Please visit http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows for more information.

Comment: As I've read the question the OP is talking about a "wubi" install, that doesn't create any partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I must have wrongly assumed it was a partition due to the way Windows Boot Loader manages the operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: it does not eliminate your Windows.

Please read this post: [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular "alongside Windows" installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation) to learn more.