# Stop windows 8 from running in background

Tags: 12.04, windows-8

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 lts on my windows 8 pc using Wubi. Though i choose to boot with ubuntu os, win 8 still runs in background. Is there any way to shut win 8 completely?

Answer (score 0):

install ubuntu using Wubi === install any windows program on windows pc

can't run it w\o start windows

Comment: if i continue using this way,will it affect my pc performance?

Answer (score 0):

The way to shutdown Windows 8 completely from the picture, is to install Ubuntu natively on your system rather than using the Wubi installer.

Read this post to understand the differences between the two:
[What's the difference between Wubi and a regular installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

Another useful post is:
[Does Wubi virtually run Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/a/488399/130574)

Comment: if i continue using this way,will it affect my pc performance?

Comment: By installing natively, you'll get more performance than by using the Wubi method.

Comment: How did you come to know that windows 8 is running in the background? In wubi install Windows 8 shouldn't be running in the background. Its only related to windows for its existance.

Comment: i had read it in some forum that windows runs in the background,and someone had also given an ntfs fix or something like that to solve the problem. Cant find that link.

Comment: As you can see [here](http://superuser.com/a/488399/130574) that should not be happening usually.

Comment: Did the answer help you?