# How do I make sure my partition returned to my primary OS after uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, wubi, uninstall, windows-8

I tried installing Ubuntu (On a new computer that came with Windows 8) so I would have a system running Unix for my school assignments.  I installed it using wubi.exe (this one: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows) and it didn't work correctly.  I have done a little research and know what the problem is and how I should approach fixing it (I'm going to try to get it to boot from USB from now on), but I need to make sure of one thing first.  I removed it by going into C:\Ubuntu\ and using the uninstall thing in that folder.  When I installed it, I gave it 25GB of my hard drive.  What I want to know is, did uninstalling it the way I did return that memory to Windows, or do I have to do something else? I want to make sure I'm not losing my hard drive as I fiddle around with getting this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wubi does not create actual partitions, so the space is still usable by your filesystem. You could run a Windows disk check to be sure, and also make sure Ubuntu is not in the list of installed programs.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, this whole dual boot thing is confusing the hell out of me

Comment: No problem. The only technical difference, in that respect, between Wubi and a regular installation is that a regular installation will literally take that portion of your hard disk (partition) for Windows, shrink it, make another partition for Ubuntu, and install it there. Whereas, with Wubi, it will create a file on the Windows partition and treat it like a partition. (Hence, you would be using NTFS, a confirmed source of heartburn: http://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)