# Partitioning in Dual Boot of Ubuntu and windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I have HP Pavilion laptop with 640 GB HDD, and have 4 drives C,D,E,F. I have installed windows 7 in C drive and now want to try Ubuntu in dual boot. Can i install Ubuntu in same C Drive in which Windows 7 is installed? Or I'll need to install Ubuntu in some other drive. Please help.

Comment: I believe you need to install Ubuntu in another drive. I haven't heard of any Ubuntu installations within a drive with Windows 7 - the file system of a Windows 7 drive isn't compatible with the Ubuntu one.

Comment: If i install Ubuntu in other drive my entire data in that drive will be lost. i have remaining 3 drives of 164, 164 and 191 GB resp. So i can't backup that much data. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer), you can install Ubuntu in Windows without having to repartition your computer. Note: there will be a performance impact: https://askubuntu.com/a/618/164093

To dual-boot, you will need to make a new parition for Ubuntu. However, if you have 4 [primary partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Primary_partition), you may have to delete one in order to make space for an [extended partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition).