# What happens if I keep both Windows and Ubuntu operating system?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, system-installation

I'm now trying Ubuntu live from a flash drive. I kind of like it, but at the same time I paid a lot for my Windows 7.

Can someone explain me what will cause/happen if I keep both of them? I heard something about the disk split (partitioning) or something. All I want to know is what happens with my 1TB hard drive. Will my documents still be there?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows

Answer (score 1):

So, there are several ways:

### If you have already installed Windows:

1. Use [Wubi](http://wubi.sourceforge.net/faq.php) .
   It's installing as usually Windows program. Bad choice - performance is low.
2. Split your had disk

***Automatically:***

Write your .iso on a CD/DVD disk and load system from it.
There are also 2 options:

Loads as LiveCD (It called "Try Ubuntu") or directly install. Ubuntu can automatically shrink Windows in both of case. It's work, but I don't like this way.

***Manually:*** (recommended):

You need split existing hard drive through Windows "Disk Management".

**Control panel** > **Disk Management**, right click on disk **Shrink Volume**. More details [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx) or [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2672-partition-volume-shrink.html). You goal is create "Unallocated" space.
It operation keep all your files.

Then simply install Ubuntu from disk on unallocated HDD space.

### If Windows not installed:

Install Windows and only after it go to "If you have already installed Windows"

---

If you're so afraid, you can buy a new hard disk and install Ubuntu on it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi & Welcome to **AskUbuntu**,

To give you a basic understanding both Windows and Linux are Operating systems but it has its own core, functionality and user friendliness. **Ubuntu** provided **Wubi** (a utility which you can install the Ubuntu system inside Windows without making any changes), considering about certain users who didn't want themselves to mess with the current system set-up they have. **Unfortunately support for Wubi has ended** with upcoming releases. You may refer "**[What's the difference between Wubi and a regular installation?](https://askubuntu.com/a/618/179042)**" for more understanding

Portioning (splitting) is required since you'll be installing Ubuntu alongside Windows. That means you're installing it on an existing portion (the space you've created) of the drive but not the drive where Windows lies. Therefore, you'll not loose any files in this way.

> **Important Note:** By installing Ubuntu, its **GRUB** bootloader itself
>   will act as the default boot by listing Windows as one. This will not
>   make any harm as you can recover Windows loader at anytime. Further,
>   make sure you're not messing up with your Windows recovery, system
>   restore partitions.. etc. Refer "**[How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/a/143482)**" in case if you want to move to Windows completely and boot through its bootloader.

Having said that, Below seen are some interesting and useful articles to begin your installation journey with.

- **[How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/a/92066/179042)** - This explains a 11.10 installation but its pretty much the same though there'll be minor modification on the process.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

yes your hard disk will split into partition. You can access windows drive in Ubuntu but you will not be able to use UBUNTU drive in window.
While installation you need to select one partition to store your Ubuntu OS at that time you can select your any empty drive and install in it. The drive which you will use for Ubuntu will not visible in windows explorer. But if you want to access that drive one third party software is there(Google it), using that software you can use that drive. I hope this texts will remove your confusion.

Comment: So I'll have 500GB for windows and 500GB for ubuntu?

Comment: if you have 1TB harddisk then you can do. or when i have installed in my laptop I allocate only 30GB HDD to Ubuntu. Its depends on you and your harddisk capacity.